# How does the Gerrit server intercept commits. Looking for technical details

Tags: git, server, gerrit

I understand that Gerrit receives git commits (using the `update` hook perhaps), and write them on a fake ref somewhere until the peer review is done, but how exactly does that process work in terms of the technical implementation? And what Git commands are involved?

Comment: Gerrit system design documentation might be of interest to you - https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-design.html - the source is also available here https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might reference the magic reference `refs/for/<branch ref>` which is used by user [when pushing new commits](https://dev.vaadin.com/review/Documentation/user-upload.html#push_create).

> To create new changes for review, simply push to the project’s magical `refs/for/'branch'` ref using any Git client tool:

```
git push ssh://sshusername@hostname:29418/projectname HEAD:refs/for/branch
```

> E.g. `john.doe` can use git push to upload new changes for the `experimental` branch of project `kernel/common`, hosted at the `git.example.com` Gerrit server:

```
git push ssh://john.doe@git.example.com:29418/kernel/common HEAD:refs/for/experimental
```

> Each new commit uploaded by the git push client will be converted into a change record on the server.
>   The remote ref `refs/for/experimental` is not actually created by Gerrit, even though the client’s status messages may say otherwise.

---

Technically, this is managed by the [cmd-receive-pack](https://github.com/gerrit-review/gerrit/blob/3a4e10f3da402c4c6f8692787c16d531f503f16c/Documentation/cmd-receive-pack.txt).

> Invoked by 'git push' and updates the project's repository with
>   the information fed from the 'git push' end.

It is implemented by [`gerrit/sshd/commands/Receive.java`](https://github.com/gerrit-review/gerrit/blob/3a4e10f3da402c4c6f8692787c16d531f503f16c/gerrit-sshd/src/main/java/com/google/gerrit/sshd/commands/Receive.java), which receives change upload over SSH using the **[Git receive-pack protocol](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-receive-pack.txt)**.